# WPF - Bind DataGrid ComboBoxColum to DataSet Table Filed with Values from another table

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, combobox, dataset

I'm trying to convert my `C#` code to xaml.

The c# code that works is

```
        g_DataGrid[TablesManagerDataGrids.DG_Idx.DG_Fixtures].SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = g_dataSet.Tables[TABLE_FIXTURES] })

        DataGridComboBoxColumn colPlatform = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
        colPlatform.Header = COL_FIXTURE_PLATFORM;
        colPlatform.ItemsSource = g_dataSet.Tables[TABLE_PLATFORM].Rows;
        colPlatform.DisplayMemberPath = "[" + COL_PLATFORM_NAME + "]";
        colPlatform.SelectedValuePath = "[" + COL_PLATFORM_IDX + "]";
        Binding temp = new Binding(COL_FIXTURE_PLATFORM);
        colPlatform.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(COL_FIXTURE_PLATFORM);
        colPlatform.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
```

That code add a ComboBox column to a datagrid to modify column `COL_FIXTURE_PLATFORM` in table `TABLE_FIXTURES`.
The values of ComboBox come form Table `TABLE_PLATFORM` in column `COL_PLATFORM_IDX`.
Strings of ComboBox DropDownList came from table TABLE_PLATFORM in column `COL_PLATFORM_NAME`.

Now I'm trying to convert this code to xaml code, but I'm too noob to this language.
The following code is the best I can write after some test, but it doesn't what I described before.

DataContext is set to my DataSet.Tables

```
            this.DataContext = g_Dataset.CurrentDataSet.Tables;
```

XAML code is:

```
    <DataGrid x:Key="DG_Fixtures_Structure" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=[Fixtures]}" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" 
                            Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Platform" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Findancestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext[Platform]}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                SelectedValuePath="Index"
                                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Platforms}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

When the datagrid is loaded the debugger show me the following error, and no data appares in the combobox.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext[Platform]; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=12880602); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
```

Is there someone that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

At the end I found a way/workaround to make it work.
The solution is to set ItemsSource in code after the class is created.

It seems that WPF cannot resolve the assignation, beacuse of, via debug, the ItemSource set for comboboxes in DataGrids is always null.